# Pairwise substraction of columns in a matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

I have a *m x n* matrix. Could anyone please help me make a new matrix resulted from the pairwise subtraction of n columns? n can be very large.

For instance, with A is a 3 x 4 matrix

```
octave:39> A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 11, 22, 33, 44; 111, 222, 333, 444]

A =

     1     2     3     4
    11    22    33    44
   111   222   333   444
```

I want to make a matrix B:

```
octave:40> B = [A(:,1)-A(:,2), A(:,1)-A(:,3), A(:,1)-A(:,4), A(:,2)-A(:,3), A(:,2)-A(:,4), A(:,3)-A(:,4)]

B =

    -1    -2    -3    -1    -2    -1
   -11   -22   -33   -11   -22   -11
  -111  -222  -333  -111  -222  -111
```

Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[m n]=size(a);
k=1;
b=zeros(m,nchoosek(n,2));
for i=1:n
  for j=i+1:n
    b(:,k)=a(:,i)-a(:,j);
    k=k+1;
  end
end
```